# Identifying which Azure WorkRole Instance is executing the Queue?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I am working on Azure Worker Roles. I have a worker role which is scaled up to 5 instance. I want to identify which Instance processed the queue item. I know, I can use [RoleEnvironment.Roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.roles.aspx) to get the list of the instances but not sure how to get the actual instance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for

```
RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Name
```